# Received error Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: python, pyqt5

I made a program which will take the logs from a camera, parse it for every line to see if the log from a file I created is in the log line and if it is count how many times the proper log is triggered.

```
from collections import deque
import sys
import os
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname('../'))))

from livelogparser.clientlogParser import ClientLogParser 
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, QObject
from PyQt5.QtGui import QTextCursor

ON_POSIX = 'posix' in sys.builtin_module_names

class Ui_logWindow(object):
    def logs(self):
        arg1 = self.lineEdit.text()
        arg2 = int(self.lineEdit_2.text())
        arg3 = self.lineEdit_3.text()
        arg4 = self.lineEdit_4.text()
        arg5 = self.lineEdit_5.text()
        arg6 = self.lineEdit_6.text()
        self.q = deque()
        #on_message comes from ClientLogParser class
        self.client = ClientLogParser(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6)
        self.client.client.on_message = self.onMsgWin
        #startListen is loop_forever()
        self.t = Thread(target=self.client.startListen, args=[])
        self.t.daemon = True
        self.t.start()

    def onMsgWin(self, client, userdata, msg):
        self.listMsg = msg.payload.decode('utf-8').rstrip()
        self.textEdit.append(self.listMsg)
        self.textEdit.moveCursor(QTextCursor.End)
        for line in self.listMsg.split('\n'):
            self.client.lp.parseEvent(line)
            self.q.append(line)
            if len(self.q) < 20:
                output_GUI = ''
                for line in self.q:
                    self.client.rp.evaluateDict(self.client.lp.dictLogs)
                    output_GUI += "COUNT:\n"
                    for key, val in self.client.lp.dictLogs.items():
                        output_GUI += f"EVT[{key}] COUNT[{val}]\n"
                        if val > 0:
                            output_GUI += f'------ the event : {key} has been triggered ------\n'
                    output_GUI += "RULES:\n"
                    for rule_idx in range(len(self.client.rp.dictRulesList)):
                        if self.client.rp.resultList[rule_idx] == 'critical':
                            sys.exit(-1)
                        if self.client.rp.resultList[rule_idx] == 'warning':
                            output_GUI += '----------succes----------\n'
                        if self.client.rp.resultList[rule_idx] == 'info':
                            output_GUI += '----------succes----------\n'
                        if self.client.rp.resultList[rule_idx] == 'succes':
                            output_GUI += '----------succes----------\n'
                        output_GUI += f"RULE:[{rule_idx}][{self.client.rp.dictRulesList[rule_idx]}]\n"
                        output_GUI += f"RESULT[{rule_idx}][{self.client.rp.resultList[rule_idx]}]\n"
                    output_GUI += "----ITERATION-END----\n"
                self.textEdit_2.append(output_GUI)
                self.textEdit_2.moveCursor(QTextCursor.End)
            else:
                sleep(5)
                self.q.clear()
                continue
```

The problem is, sometime the program is working and it prints me in `textEdit_2` what I need, sometimes it is crashing with error *"Segmentation fault (core dumped)"*.

I tried to make a queue which will take 20 line (because the log lines are coming very fast like 30-40 in 3-4 sec), parse them and add them into `editText_2`, sleep for 5 sec and then do it again, but is the same result.
`edit_Text` is appending every log line as it is from the camera.
Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. If anyone have this problem: putting a `sleep(.1)` right before the line from the log is readed can be helpful:

```
def onMsgWin(self, client, userdata, msg):
    self.listMsg = msg.payload.decode('utf-8').rstrip()
    self.textEdit.append(self.listMsg)
    self.textEdit.moveCursor(QTextCursor.End)
    for line in self.listMsg.split('\n'):
        sleep(.1)
        self.client.lp.parseEvent(line)`
```

Comment: No, you didn't solve it. Sooner or later it's going to happen again, because you're trying to access widgets from external threads, which you can't, because widgets are ***not*** thread-safe. You must use a QThread with custom signals.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).